# Adding a space to the date part of a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like below:

```
Your 23rd birthday is on 13/12/2020 of this year.
```

I want to get output as

```
Your 23rd birthday is on 13/12/2020  of this year.
```

Adding an extra space after the date part.

The date can be any date.

I tried this regex to get the date part.

```
re.search(r'(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4,})',s).group()
```

And it correctly fetches the date part.

```
'13/12/2020'
```

So I thought of replacing this regex with similar but a space added:

```
re.sub(r'(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4,})', r'(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4,}) ',s)
```

But it throws an error:

```
error: bad escape \d at position 1
```

Comment: You shouldn't just repeat the regex, you just want to replace it with `r'\1 '`

Comment: You can omit the capturing group and match the date followed by the space and replace with `\g<0>` followed by a space. https://regex101.com/r/phslBJ/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\1` to refer the substring that the pattern matches:

```
re.sub(r'(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4,})', r'\1 ',s)
```

If you wanna do it for *N* expressions just use `\{number}` (max is 99):

```
re.sub(r'(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4,})|(Shipment)', r'\1\2 ',s)
```

Comment: This is good. It worked. Quick follow up if u dont mind. I can have a string where there can be a date as above or inplace of date, I can have a word "Shipment Origin". I want to add an extra space between Shipment and Origin. In other words possible to add an OR condition in regex where it checks for that date pattern or "Shipment"?

Comment: edited the answer

Comment: thank u. I was doing the same but in replacement string I only kept \1. I was wondering if it is checking either of these two so there would be only 1 group present at one time. So was not sure why we need to specify both \1\2